# Print a python statement multiple times with different results

Tags: python-3.x, replication, exponent

I'm in an introduction to Python course and I'm writing some code that I'm trying to improve. The assignment is to accept an input, print that value to the nth power and also print the exponent.

Here's my code:

```
start = input("Please enter a starting value: ")
print("exp    res\n1      " + str(int(start)**1) + "\n")
print("2      " + str(int(start)**2) + "\n")
print("3      " + str(int(start)**3) + "\n")
print("4      " + str(int(start)**4) + "\n")
```

My question is whether (for an intro course and WITHOUT using loops), is there a way in python to print one string and replicate it while ++'ing the exponent?

Fake code that hopefully explains what I want:

```
exponent = 0    
print((str(exponent++) + "      " + str(int(start)**exponent)))*4)
```

Maybe I'm overanalyzing a Chapter 1 assignment, but I'm curious.

Comment: You would need to use a loop of some kind.

Comment: It might be dangerous to use if it exists.  Your instructor might consider something like that "loop shorthand" or "implicit looping."   I'd also avoid over-compressed syntax like that for writing anything I need to maintain.

Comment: You cannot do `print(exp+=1)` in python. Instead define an `increment` function which will return an incremented value and use it as `print(str(increment(exponent))` .